# Style break on flexbox chat

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Does anyone know why the image breaks onto a new line when the bubbles sides are constrained?

If I change the bubbles max-width to calc(100% - 70px) the image doesn't break although I get the last word on a new line, which also breaks the style.

```css
body {
  background: #f0f3f6;
}

.messages {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.scrolling {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scrolled {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.message {
  line-height: 1em;
  display: block;
  margin: 18px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.message .image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
}

.message img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 150px;
}

.message .bubble {
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.message .bubble::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.message .time {
  color: #838689;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.9em;
  width: 100%;
}

.message-left {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.message-left .time {
  left: 50px;
}

.message-left .bubble {
  color: #343434;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.message-left .bubble::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #fff;
}

.message-right {
  flex: 0;
  align-self: flex-end;
  float: right;
}

.message-right .time {
  text-align: right;
  right: 50px;
}

.message-right .bubble {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #0084ff;
}

.message-right .bubble::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #0084ff;
}
```

```html
<div ref="messages" class="messages scrolling">
  <div class="scrolled">
    <div class="message message-left">
      <span class="time">1 min ago</span>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15492548_1291266807563287_6299338365875926813_n.jpg?oh=b2c7a59d1666247350753be9002e6884&oe=5AB71F93" />
      </div>
      <div class="bubble">
        This message has the same problem.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message message-right">
      <span class="time">1 min ago</span>
      <div class="bubble">
        A small comment.
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15492548_1291266807563287_6299338365875926813_n.jpg?oh=b2c7a59d1666247350753be9002e6884&oe=5AB71F93" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message message-right">
      <span class="time">1 min ago</span>
      <div class="bubble">
        A really long message, designed to be big enough to create a multi-line comment.
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15492548_1291266807563287_6299338365875926813_n.jpg?oh=b2c7a59d1666247350753be9002e6884&oe=5AB71F93" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Original JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd9udy81)

Comment: Hi Chris, Could I ask how you managed to get the code snippet to work, I couldn't create the post due to more code than description.

Comment: he has more reputation than you ;) so he's able to edit without the limiation you have

Comment: What's the difference in rendering when using or not using calc(100% - 70px)? I could not tell the difference?

Comment: The last word appears on a new line. This only happens to the text on the right though.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't doing it because I didn't add the bootstrap reset.

Comment: Here's the update, I added the problemic CSS at the top and the fix below the max-width of bubble. Although the image is breaking again: http://jsfiddle.net/gd9udy81/6/.

Comment: @orabis Try removing that line below the max-width and see how it looks. That's where the image stays in the correct place and the last word breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message` element is `display: block`.

If you use `display: flex` instead, the image and text are forced to remain on a single line (because a default setting of a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap`).

[revised demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/gd9udy81/7/)

If you don't want the images to shrink, add `flex-shrink: 0` to the items. (By default, flex items are set to `flex-shrink: 1`, allowing them to shrink so they don't overflow the container).

[revised demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/gd9udy81/8/)